# How to exclude increasing counter_cache on some state changes?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, counter, counter-cache

```
ShiftNote
  belongs_to :shift, counter_cache: true
  workflow do
    state :scheduled
    state :canceled
  end
Shift
  has_many :shift_notes

  scope :opened, lambda {
    locked
    .where("shift_notes_count < shifts.limit")
  }
```

How to not increase `shift_notes_count` when during **ShiftEntry** creation `shift_note.state.canceled? => true`

Right now my `shift_entries_count` is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a conditional on the belongs to, I think this is what you're asking for:

```
belongs_to :shift, :counter_cache => lambda {|c| !c.state.canceled }
```

Comment: Rails does not support conditional counters.